# Open different activities for different button clicks

Tags: android, android-layout

I am making a voting app which stores click in firebase. When any of the two buttons is pressed, it should to go to a common layout activity(votes.java). This happens for Btn1 but the app crashes when clicking Btn2.

MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.os.Handler;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Firebase mRootRef;
private Button mBtn1;
private Button mBtn2;
int counter = 0;
int counter1 = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    mBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    mBtn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    mBtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.equals(mBtn1)) {
                Intent i1= new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Votes.class);
                startActivity(i1);
                mRootRef = new Firebase("https://voting-cf0fa.firebaseio.com/House/Jupiter/Player 1");
                Firebase mRefChild = mRootRef.child("Votes");
                counter++;
                mRefChild.setValue(counter);

            }

            mRootRef = new Firebase("https://voting-cf0fa.firebaseio.com/House/Jupiter/Player 2");
            mBtn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (v.equals(mBtn2)) {
                        Intent i2= new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Votes.class);
                        startActivity(i2);
                        Firebase mRefChild = mRootRef.child("Votes");
                        counter1++;
                        mRefChild.setValue(counter1);

                    }
                }

            });
        }
    });

}}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Stack trace please from your log cat.

Comment: your 2nd button listener is inside 1st listener, try put outside from the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your click listener for button 2 is inside the click listener for button 1. You need to initialize different onClick Listeners for different buttons.

Try this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        mBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        mBtn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        mBtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                Intent i1= new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Voted.class);
                startActivity(i1);
                mRootRef = new Firebase("https://voting-cf0fa.firebaseio.com/House/Jupiter/Player 1");
                Firebase mRefChild = mRootRef.child("Votes");
                counter++;
                mRefChild.setValue(counter);
            });

        mBtn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                mRootRef = new Firebase("https://voting-cf0fa.firebaseio.com/House/Jupiter/Player 2");
                Intent i2= new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Voted2.class);
                startActivity(i2);
                Firebase mRefChild = mRootRef.child("Votes");
                counter1++;
                mRefChild.setValue(counter1);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

This should fix it :

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Firebase mRootRef;
private Button mBtn1;
private Button mBtn2;
int counter = 0;
int counter1 = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    mBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    mBtn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    mBtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

            Intent i1= new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Voted.class);
            startActivity(i1);
            mRootRef = new Firebase("https://voting-cf0fa.firebaseio.com/House/Jupiter/Player 1");
            Firebase mRefChild = mRootRef.child("Votes");
            counter++;
            mRefChild.setValue(counter);
        });


        mBtn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                mRootRef = new Firebase("https://voting-cf0fa.firebaseio.com/House/Jupiter/Player 2");
                Intent i2= new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Voted2.class);
                startActivity(i2);
                Firebase mRefChild = mRootRef.child("Votes");
                counter1++;
                mRefChild.setValue(counter1);
            }

        });

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are trying to handle click listener of Button 2 inside Button 1. 
This should fix it :

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Firebase mRootRef;
private Button mBtn1;
private Button mBtn2;
int counter = 0;
int counter1 = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    mBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    mBtn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    mBtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

            Intent i1= new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Voted.class);
            startActivity(i1);
            mRootRef = new Firebase("https://voting-cf0fa.firebaseio.com/House/Jupiter/Player 1");
            Firebase mRefChild = mRootRef.child("Votes");
            counter++;
            mRefChild.setValue(counter);
        });


        mBtn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                mRootRef = new Firebase("https://voting-cf0fa.firebaseio.com/House/Jupiter/Player 2");
                Intent i2= new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Voted2.class);
                startActivity(i2);
                Firebase mRefChild = mRootRef.child("Votes");
                counter1++;
                mRefChild.setValue(counter1);
            }

        });

}
}
```

Comment: The counter in Firebase doesn't get increased anymore now. It would increase before.